# Given an array of numbers,form a subset such that it can represent(addition of numbers is allowed) any number in the given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an  array which contains all the numbers from 1 to 100 and any number from the array(1 to 100) is given.

we need to form a subset with minimum no of elements from the given array,such that we can represent the given number.

We can only add numbers from the subset to form given number if required.

We can not add element twice from the same index of the subset.

```
Few Examples:
Ex:given an array of elements 1,2,3.
Ans:1,2.
```

If the given number is 1.We can represent 1 from our subset directly.

If the given number is 2.We can represent 2 from our subset directly.

If the given number is 3.we can represent 3 with 1+2 from our subset.

We can actually duplicates the numbers while forming the subsets like

```
Ex:given an array of elements 1,2.
Ans:1,2 or 1,1.
```

The answer cannot be just 1.As we cannot add same 1 twice to form 2.

A friend of mine asked me this question and I am stuck on how to procede..

Any suggestions would greatly help ...

Also I could not come up some decent title for this question..Is this a classical problem?

Comment: In your second example shouldn't the given array be `1,1,2`? otherwise the sentence immediately after: "The answer cannot be just 1.As we cannot add same 1 twice to form 2." is in contrast with the answer.

Comment: @LeartS we can repeat the elements of the given array while forming the subarray. So we can form [1,1] as a subset. But the subset cannot be just [1]..What I meant above is we cannot add element from the same index of the subset twice...

Comment: does the array contains all the number from 1 to 100? Is the array sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in a greedy manner:  Repeatedly choose the first missing value.

It is not clear whether your array contains all the numbers from 1 to 100, or just a subset of them.

It is also not clear whether you have to make all numbers from 1 to the largest number in the array, or just a few target values.  I will assume you have to be able to construct all the intermediate values as well.

### Assuming all numbers are present

First we must include the number 1.

Next we include the number 2.  We can now make everything up to 3.

So next include the number 4.  We can now make everything up to 1+2+4=7.

So next include the number 8.  We can now make everything up to 1+2+4+8=15.

...

So next include the number 2^k.  We can now make everything up to 1+2+...+2^k = 2^(k+1).

So for 100 numbers you will need 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 and will be able to make every number up to 127.

### Assuming a subset of numbers are present

Suppose the array might be a subset such as [1,2,3,5,7,9,15].  The same basic approach works, but this time we need to choose the largest number in the array that is less than or equal to the first missing value.

First include 1.

Next include 2, we can now make numbers up to 3.

Next our first missing value is 4, but we don't have a 4 to pick, so instead pick the 3.  We can now reach up to 1+2+3=6.

Next our first missing value is 7, so we can pick the 7.  Our reach is now 1+2+3+7=13.

Next our missing value is 14, but we don't have a 14, so instead pick the 9, etc.

Comment: I believe this algorithm would be optimal if picking numbers more than once were not allowed.  But here we could sometimes cover the lowest uncovered number with a second copy of one of the earlier numbers, and there could be several choices that work, and which one gets picked might have repercussions down the road...

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am not sure I have understood the question correctly so you may well be right.  However, my belief is that if you arrange the chosen numbers in increasing order, then each new chosen number must be less than (or equal to) 1 plus the sum of the preceding numbers, and that altogether they will cover all numbers from 1 to the sum of the chosen numbers.  For this reason I believe the greedy algorithm will be optimal - but I will readily change my mind if presented with a counter example!

Comment: @j_random_hacker  I agree.  In my answer I have said that I am assuming that you have to be able to construct all the intermediate values as well (i.e. your set is impossible to cover because you cannot cover 1).  If this assumption is not true, then I accept that the greedy algorithm is flawed.

Comment: Whoops, my last comment was wrong ({2,3,4,7} *can* be covered with {2,3,4}) so I deleted it...  And I agree that the requirements are unclear.  So your approach is at the very least a good heuristic :)

Comment: Consider {1,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}. I suppose, your algoritm gives {1,8,10,12,14,16}, while {1,1,8,11,14} is better.